# Gridview column header set by textbox input?

Tags: c#

So I have a gridview in a windows form application and when I click my button the gridview is populated, the title column/row reads Tag (because I set it that way(below code)) but what if I wanted the Tag title to be replaced with what ever is typed in a textbox, how would I change the below code?

```
Tag = n.Element("GroupName").Value
```

Full code:

```
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(tagUri);
        var Tag = xDoc.Descendants("Group")
            .Select(n => new
            {

                Tag = n.Element("GroupName").Value, // Tag in this line represents the column name, I would like this changed to be a textbox input. 
            })
            .ToList();

        dataGridView4.DataSource = Tag;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the column's header afterwards:

```
datagridView4.Columns[0].HeaderText = textbox1.Text;
```

Comment: Hey Nico no this isnt what im after I want the Tag to be set by the textbox text, im after `textbox1.Text = n.Element("GroupName").Value`in a sense. Obviously you cant do that tho. This is just to set the **title** of the gridview. Not the contents.

Comment: I really don't get it. Is the textbox an input or output of this operation? Do you want to set the textbox' text to a combination of all tags?

Comment: Ah.. now everything is crystal clear. I edited the answer. This should do what you want :)